# How do I pass environment variable in script command

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, cypress

I have below cypress nodeJS script commands in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
"cy:run": "npx cypress run --browser chrome",
"cy:parallel" : "cypress-parallel -s cy:run -t 4 -d cypress/e2e/features/ -m false -a '\"--env ENV=${ENVI}\"'" 
}
```

`-a` is the argument that is dynamic, That I want to pass while running the tests like `ENVI=QA` or `ENVI=LIVE`

I have tried following things but did not work for me

```
SET ENVI=QA
npm run cy:parallel
```

`ENVI=QA npm run cy:parallel`

`$ENVI=QA npm run cy:parallel`

Please share the correct way to pass the argument from the command-line

Comment: `ENVI=QA npm run cy:parallel` is the correct way to pass environment variables to a command in bash and zsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with below command:

set the environment variable value like below:

`$env:ENVI=QA` (On Windows)

and change script command as follow:

Instead of `ENV=${ENVI}`, Use `ENV=%ENVI%`

```
"cy:parallel" : "cypress-parallel -s cy:run -t 4 -d cypress/e2e/features/ -m false -a '\"--env ENV=%ENVI%\"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would use `CYPRESS_` prefix.

To make things easier (independent of OS) use the package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

**Install**

```js
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

**package.json**

```js
"scripts": {
  "cy:run": "cross-env CYPRESS_ENVI=QA cypress run",
  ...
}
```

Tested with a simple test:

```js
it('checks cross-env has set up CYPRESS_ENVI', () => {
  expect(Cypress.env('ENVI')).to.eq('QA')                // passes
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `--` to separate the npm command from the cypress command, and everything after it is passed as arguments to the cypress-parallel command:

```
npm run cy:parallel -- --env ENV=QA
```